# How to open Facebook Share Dialog from CursorAdapter?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

Currently I'm developing an simple app which has ListView with text & I would like to open share dialog through which user can share text on Facebook wall.

I'm using CursorAdapter to populate data & there is ImageButton upon click of this button user will be able to share text message directly .

I have tried to use Share Dialog in separate Activity & now I want to include inside this adapter code. 
So , how open ShareDialog from Cursor Adapter code as it requires Activity reference ? Any example would be appreciated.

Here is my CursorAdapter code :

```
    public class MessageAdapterForListView extends CursorAdapter {

    private static final String TAG = MessageAdapterForListView.class.getSimpleName();
    Context mContext;
    Cursor mCursor;

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    private TextView textView;

    private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
    private ProfileTracker profileTracker;

    public MessageAdapterForListView(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
        mContext = context;
        mCursor = c;
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

        View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_message, parent, false);

        return retView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        holder.messageTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.msg_title);
        holder.shareOnFb = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.share_on_fb);
        holder.shareOnFb.setFocusable(false);


        final String message = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.MESSAGE_TEXT));
        String msgTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.MESSAGE_TITLE));
        String msgSerialId  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseManager.MESSAGE_SERIAL_ID));




        holder.messageText.setText(message);
        holder.messageTitle.setText(msgTitle);

        ShareMessageOnFbHandler shareMessageOnFbHandler = new ShareMessageOnFbHandler(msgSerialId,msgTitle,message);
        holder.shareOnFb.setOnClickListener(shareMessageOnFbHandler);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }

    class ShareMessageOnFbHandler implements View.OnClickListener {

        private String mid , mtitle,mtext;
        public ShareMessageOnFbHandler(String msgSerialId , String msgTitle , String msgText)
        {
            this.mid = msgSerialId;
            this.mtitle = msgTitle;
            this.mtext = msgText;

        }

        public void onClick(View view) {


            Log.d(TAG,"Share Message For : "+this.mid +" Msg Title : "+this.mtitle +" Message : "+this.mtext);

        //From here I want to share text message on Facebook
        // Also ShareDialog requires Activity in constructor so , how do I get activity instance in adapter class

       }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView messageTitle,messageText;
        ImageButton shareOnFb;

    }
}



  [1]: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android
```

Comment: So what is your question. You said that official documents say it is not allowed. You still want to know how to do it so Facebook bans your app?

Comment: @WizKid thanks for the suggestion . I have updated my question .

Comment: Facebook Platform Policy say that it is not allowed https://developers.facebook.com/policy . If you want your app banned just give me your app ID and I can have that happen

Comment: Okay ,I'm not intended to violate Facebook policy anytime. I have updated my question . Now my question is not related to facebook policy so , you can answer it now .

Comment: Because it is not allowed it is also not possible. Why would Facebook make something possible if it is never allowed?

Comment: @WizKid I'm asking question about functionality related to android , please read question twice . I'm asking "How to open Facebook Share  Dialog (which is available in Facebook APIs) from Android CursorAdapter" ?